# xcode 8 simulators are not showing after install xcode 8.1

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8

After installing xcode 8.1

I had created one project with it. And its shows all simulators.
But when I open same project with xcode 8. It not showing any simulators.

I tried many solution like,

window->device -> add simulator (all simulor are shown in list but not get open to run with simulators). Refer images
[image][image]

restart xcode and system also.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode > Preferences > Components > choose to install the simulator you want from the list.

Comment: There is option for download older iOS simulator only.

Answer (score 0):

I find one solution that if you are installing using .xip than follow this steps.

1. quit any running Xcode or simulator
2. move .xip file to application Folder where all installed app exist
3. Extract xip file over there
4. After extraction open New xcode
5. Install addition components if this option window comes.

Check there should be all simulator listed on your new Xcode.